# Customizing knowledge

Tags: knowledge, community

I am working on communities and wondered if there is a way i can use Out-Of-Box -knowledge for communities but instead of accessing it via tab I need to show it on Customized VF page. The Community template we are using is (Visual Force + Tabs).

Comment: You can always provide via link .The URL will be something like domain/communityname/knowledge/knowledgeHome.apexp

Comment: dont think there is way .may be look at knowledge developer guide and build an simple VF page .That has detailed code on how to approach via customized solution via apex and VF

Comment: when I am passing link , it takes me to knowledge tab(standard OOB knowledge for community), what I am trying to accomplish is the base knowledge should be intact but re-skin the look. If we decide to built in custom page for Knowledge we will loose OOB functionality of Knowledge. Thanks though, I am exploring the Knowledge Developer Guide.

Comment: aditi there is no way we can style that standard OO page .Only way i could think for you is to install some package like PKB that gives nice look and feel .Also developer guide provides all knowledge article functionality .Search,sort and hopefully with some google you should be able to do rate